# How to take a screenshot of a control in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use the following lines to do the screenshot but the image isn't specific to control...it is taken outside the control range.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZRIp.png)

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location.X,
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location.Y, tableLayoutPanel1.Width, tableLayoutPanel1.Height);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location.X, 
              this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location.Y, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Comment: [DrawToBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) ? FYI If you want to explore methods exposed by an type, you can type the name of a variable followed by a period `.` and Visual Studio will list the public methods, properties, and fields.

Comment: I got the code wrong. Here is a working version: `Rectangle rect = tableLayoutPanel1.RectangleToScreen(tableLayoutPanel1.ClientRectangle);// or tableLayoutPanel1.Bounds

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, rect.Size);`

Comment: draw to bitmap won't save because i want to save rich text box's and they don't have the propertie to save with that function

Comment: I wrote your code but same problem...gets the image out of the table.....

Comment: Do you mean my code? It works fine here. Please show your current version and the current result!

Comment: It's taking the screenshot but it takes the image from screen's pixel location not from forms control location but i will try to save the location with another code i found

Comment: This makes no sense. rect.Location is indeed in screen coordinates as it should be to tell CopyFromScreen where to start copying. You must have made a copy error.

Comment: Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(tableLayoutPanel1.Location.X, tableLayoutPanel1.Location.Y, tableLayoutPanel1.Width, tableLayoutPanel1.Height);
                    Rectangle rectangle = ctrl.RectangleToScreen(rect);
                    Point point = PointToScreen(ctrl.Location);
                    Point point2 = new Point(0, 0);

                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                    g.CopyFromScreen(point, point2, bmp.Size);
                    bmp.Save(path);       this work but ty